# Is the set $\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

> Are the function $f_1(x)=1,f_2(x)=\sin x,f_3(x)=\sin^2x$ linearly independent?

My try:I calculated the Wronskian and got $2\cos x\cos 2x+\sin x\sin 2x$.so what should I conclude and why?

Comment: What is the space?

Comment: Nothing is mentioned.

Comment: And the Field is $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: yes ,i think so.

Comment: Is the definition of linear independence different than for finite vector spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $c_1.f_1+c_2.f_2+c_3.f_3=0\implies c_1.1+c_2\sin x+c_3.\sin^2x=0$.

Putting $x=0;\implies c_1=0$.

Putting $x=\frac{\pi}{2}\implies c_2+c_3=0$;

Putting $x=-\frac{\pi}{2}\implies -c_2+c_3=0$;

Solving the above two equations give $c_2=c_3=0$

Comment: you mean to say linearly independent.Right?

Comment: Yes that's right@MatheMagic